# Knowing when there is a rewarded video available

Tags: android, admob

I've developed an android app which has a button to show a rewarded video. Sometimes there is no available videos, so the user press the button but nothing happens. Is there a way to know if there is a video available to show the button only if there are videos?

If is not possible to know, when the user presses the button, can I detect that there are no videos, in order to show a toast with a message?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video#set_up_event_notifications write logic of button visibility inside onRewardedVideoAdLoaded or in your button click you can check for mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()

Comment: Yes, it works! Write it as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Rewarded Video event notifications to identify whether Rewarded Video ad was loaded correctly. link - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video#set_up_event_notifications

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Write logic here to disable/enable button in question
}
```

Or on your button click check if rewardedvideo is loaded and based on that take appropriate action

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Take action.
        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }else{
               //Show message to user
       }

    }
});
```